# Automatization of a conditional function through the use of an array to test postdata variables

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, post

I have some problems to make the following automatization:

I get from a form a lot of variables such as $a and $b.
I would like to automatize a conditional test depending on the variables I obtain.

```
$test = array('a','b');
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($test);$i++)
```

For the 1st variable a, the working code is:

```
if ( $postdata->a !=${$test[$i]}){echo "different";} else {echo "same";}
```

For the 2nd variable b, the working code is:

```
if ( $postdata->b !=${$test[$i]}){echo "different";} else {echo "same";}
```

I would like to automatize it thanks to the array like this:

```
if ( $postdata->$test[$i] !=${$test[$i]}){echo "different";} else {echo "same";}
```

but `$postdata->$test[$i]` doesn't work, even echo $test[$i] gives 'a' and 'b'.
I tried several "writing" but I couldn't solve it.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of making your code too complex with `$test[$i]` and `for loop` instead use `foreach`. Hope this will work fine.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/780378) `contains sample input`

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$test=array('a','b');
foreach($test as $i => $value)
{
    if ($postdata->{$value} != ${$value})
    {
        echo "different";
    } 
    else
    {
        echo "same";
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Sahil,

It works fine !
Thank you very much, I will look deeper on the foreach function !
Have a nice evening ;)